# Salesforce Rest API - Inserting values into Lookup fields

Tags: node.js, rest, salesforce

Inserting 200 records at a time (JSON array) into a custom object using the Salesforce REST API. Example with one record:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes" : {"type" : "Timecard__c"},
      "Project__c": "a9S1F0000004LHDUA2",
      "Milestone__c": "a9F1F00000007GOUAY",
      "Resource__c": "0031F00000TApKqQAL",
      "Date__c": "2020-08-16",
      "Hours__c": 7,
      "Notes__c": "Did some work"
    },
  ]
}
```

The first three fields are lookups to other objects. The data I'm given to insert has names for the lookup fields (eg Project__c = "Canoe reconstruction", Milestone__c = "Rebuild gunwales", Resource__c = "John Smith".

My current plan is to generate arrays of Projects, Milestones, and Resources containing the Ids and Names then patch the JSON I have to load.

Does the Salesforce REST API offer a way to set the values of the Lookups to the text name such that it would find the Id on its own or is my current approach the most efficient way to handle this?

Here's the code I'm using for the processed data load...

```
const submitTimecards = async() => {
  const token = await getAccessToken()
  const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('timecards.json', 'utf-8'))
  const response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${salesforceUrl}/composite/sobjects`,
    data,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `OAuth ${token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })

  return response
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `Name` it's bit tricky. SF "natural" way would be to specify a helper field marked as external id (ideally it'd be marked unique too) and then you can use your references. *"Dear Salesforce, I don't care what's your internal primary key of that Account record I need to link to, on my end it's 12345, go do your magic, look it up yourself".*

It's in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm?search_text=patch, look for example that says "Upserting Records and Associating with an External ID". It might not be very clear but if you have SF admin in team he/she should know what can be done with "upsert" operation in Data Loader, same principles would apply. I have an example that upserts multiple objects in one go, it'll be bit too crazy but try to read it: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/274696/799

Or you could batch multiple requests into one all-or-none API call. It'll be like series of instructions to SF, not multiple round trips to you and having to cache results somewhere. In that call you could run queries and then use their temporary results in your final request. It'll look bit like https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_record_manipulation.htm or https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2017/01/simplify-your-api-code-with-new-composite-resources.html (scroll to the "A Simple Example, Now Using Composite!" part)

```
{
    "compositeRequest" : [{
        "method" : "POST",
        "url" : "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account",
        "referenceId" : "refAccount",
        "body" : {
            "Name" : "My New Account"
        }
    },{
        "method" : "GET",
        "url" : "/services/data/v38.0/query/?q=select+id+from+contact+where+name='Howard+Jones'",
        "referenceId" : "refContact"                               
    },{
        "method" : "PATCH",
        "url" : "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/@{refContact.records[0].Id}",
        "referenceId" : "refContactUpdated",
        "body" : {
            "AccountId" : "@{refAccount.id}"
        }
    }]
}
```

The downside is that with `composite` you won't be able to do all 200 in 1 go.

> You can have up to 25 subrequests in a single call. Up to 5 of these
> subrequests can be sObject Collections or query operations, including
> Query and QueryAll requests.